How to fix TranslateX doesn't work on slider?

  const slider = useRef();
  let tx = 0;

  const slideForward = () => {
    if (tx > -400) {
      tx -= 100;
    }
    slider.current.style.transform = `translateX(`${tx}%`)`;
  };
  const slideBackward = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="Customers">
      <img src={nextIcon} alt="" className="nextIcon" onClick={slideForward} />
      <img src={nextIcon} className="backIcon" alt="" onClick={slideBackward} />

      {customerData.map((record) => (
        <div key={record.id} className="slider">
          <ul ref={slider}>
            <li>
              <img src={record.logo} alt={`${record.company}-Logo`} />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Customers;

Why the slider doesn't move and somehow when I click the button next shows only last picture?
I want the slider to move 100% each time I press the next button

You should use useState to store tx value and use that value for css updates. Example: const [tx, setTx] = useState(0);

Can you please clarify more on how to add it on this code? @M.ÇağlarTUFAN

An extra pair of backticks are in the literal being assigned to transform.
Change
slider.current.style.transform = `translateX(`${tx}%`)`;

to
slider.current.style.transform = `translateX(${tx}%)`;

Then the slider ref is assigned to every ul element in the loop.
Change
  {customerData.map((record) => (
    <div key={record.id} className="slider">
      <ul ref={slider}>
        <li>
          <img src={record.logo} alt={`${record.company}-Logo`} />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  ))}

to
<div className="slider" ref={slider}>
  <ul>
   {customerData.map((record) => (
     <li key={record.id}>
       <img src={record.logo} alt={`${record.company}-Logo`} />
     </li>
   ))}
 </ul>
</div>

Here is some code:
Demo

I still have the same problem of images not sliding but only last picture appears when I click
Any thoughts why?

I updated my answer with a Demo. Hope this helps and enjoy.
